# Scala: Getting error - mapPartitionsWithIndex is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a beginner in Apache Spark and Scala. I'm getting an error in while executing below code:

```
val z = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6),2)

//print the content with partition labels
def myfunc(index: Int, iter: Iterator[(int)] ): Iterator[String] = {
    iter.toList.map( x => "[Part Id: " + index + " ,val:" + x + "]").iterator
}

z.mapPartitionsWithIndex(myfunc).collect
error : value mapPartitionsWithIndex is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]
```

I coudn't understand what is wrong in the code? Can any one explain? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Iterator[Int]` not `Iterator[(Int)]`.

```
val z = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

def func(index: Int, iter: Iterator[Int]): Iterator[String] = {
  iter.map(x => s"[Part ID: ${index}, val: ${x}]")
}

z.mapPartitionsWithIndex(func).collect()
```

Or just as follows:

```
z.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ case (index, iter) =>
    iter.map(x => s"[Part ID: ${index}, val: ${x}]")
}.collect()
```